# Expansion file download errors. AAC File Validation / Resource could not be found

Tags: android, expansion-files

I'm experiencing 2 different errors, one from the tablet and another from the phone.

I've uploaded a ZIP uncompressed file into the Google Play Store with 4 audio files (more than a day ago) and I'm having some issues.

1. When trying to download from one device, it downloads the Expansion file and at 99% the error "AAC File Validation Failed" appears.

   This was due to a 'false' argument in "SampleDownloaderActivity" -> 'protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)'

   Anyway, executing

   ```
   Helpers.doesFileExist(this, str, 27959282L, false);
   ```

   returns TRUE and the mp3 files inside the Zip (obb) work/plays correct.
2. When trying to download from another device, this appears: "Download failed because the resources could not be found".

   I've found in console a message that, I think, is pointing me to the culprit.

   > [licensechecker] Could not bind to service.

After searching, I've tried:

- For the 1st issue, commenting the CRC check. It didn't help.
- For the 2nd issue, following the instructions of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807048/download-expansion-files-on-tablet). It didn't work either.

I haven't found any solution. I'm experiencing the same results with the working sources of 'DND-AAC' (obtained from Google Code).

Comment: Please provide a proper answer instead of putting answer in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution (Same as answered/edited in the question):

1st problem: SampleDownloaderActivity

```
   private static final XAPKFile[] xAPKS = {
    new XAPKFile(
            true, // true signifies a main file
            2001, // the version of the APK that the file was uploaded
               // against
            27959282L // the length of the file in bytes
    ) /*
     , new XAPKFile(...)
      //*/
    };
```

The hardcoded info were not correctly set. Also, I didnt have a patch file, so i've had to eliminate it from the array.

2n Problem: Play Store app was missing!! There was a direct-access but no app (no clue about why). I made an APK backup from the phone's one and installed in the tablet, then reboot the tablet and all worked fine.

Comment: Check the expansion file name, and its length

Comment: what length did you put? i put total file size (not size in disk) is that correct?
Also my expansion file is:
main.7.com.testsdevelops.coolgame.obb

I made a zip and then changed .zip for .obb. is that correct?

Comment: solved it uploading a beta version.
step by step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709963/expansion-file-android-download-failed-because-the-resources-could-not-be-fo/23894948#23894948

Comment: Glad you could :) You can also place your expansion file in the expansion folder of your android device to test it (at least it was what i did)

Comment: yes, but sometime you will need to test the dlwnload process